# Multipage Tiff compression

Tags: java, tiff

I've seen a few questions regarding multipage tiffs and a few questions about compression, but none (that I've seen) linking the two. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539057/convert-java-awt-image-to-tiff-byte-array-with-compression) is as close as I've seen and puts me incredibly close, so I hope. I went into the Oracle forum thread mentioned (it is talking about a multipage PDF to TIFF with compression) and I think I'm closish to having the code finished to do this. Can anyone assist? I'm going to remove the try/catches to try and shorten this down a hair (basically all they did was output a message in console and return false).

```
 public static boolean CompressedTiff(List<BufferedImage> images, File path)
 {
    if (!path.getParentFile().exists())
         path.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    path.createNewFile();
    ImageOutputStream ios;
         ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(path);

    Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriters = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF");
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)imageWriters.next();
    writer.setOutput(ios);
    TIFFImageWriteParam writeParam = (TIFFImageWriteParam)writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    writeParam.setCompressionMode(2);
    writeParam.setCompressionType("LZW"); 
    writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

    for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
    {
        ImageTypeSpecifier spec = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(images.get(i));
        javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(spec, writeParam);
        IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(images.get(i), null, metadata);
        writer.writeToSequence(iioImage, writeParam);
        images.get(i).flush();//modified after release.

        images.get(i).flush();
        writer.endWriteSequence();
        ios.flush();
        writer.dispose();
        ios.close();
    }
    return true;

}
```

It failed out on the next pass at writer.writeToSequence saying I needed to call prepareWriteSequence. I changed it to

```
 writer.prepareWriteSequence(metadata);
 writer.writeToSequence(iioImage, writeParam);
```

also removed the earlier writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);

and it appears to be navigating the files properly, however, the output isn't of any type of renderable tif. Multipage or otherwise.

I have JAI installed so if it is possible to use that in some way to achieve the compressed image, that'd be fantastic. The code I am using that generates a TIFF is using this, but I haven't seen anything that worked as far as adding compression to the pages.

edit: I added a bunch of ios.flush(); ios.close(); calls in the catch blocks and it prevents the non-renderable TIFF issue. However, it isn't adding any page beyond the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it helps, this is code that I use for modifying a TiffImageWriteParam to set the compression:

```
try {
    jWriteParam.setCompressionMode(_compression != TiffCompression.NO_COMPRESSION 
                  ? ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT : ImageWriteParam.MODE_DISABLED);

    if (_compression != TiffCompression.NO_COMPRESSION) {
        // this code corrects the compression if, say, the client code asked for
        // CCITT but the actual image pixel format was CMYK or some other non-1 bit
        // image type.
        TiffCompression mode = recastToValidCompression(_compression, pf);
        jWriteParam.setCompressionType(getCompressionType(mode));
        TIFFCompressor compressor = getTiffCompressor(mode, jWriteParam, shouldUsePredictor(pf));
        jWriteParam.setTIFFCompressor(compressor);
        if (_compression == TiffCompression.JPEG_COMPRESSION) {
            // Java supports setting to 1.0 (ie 100), but it will not actually do lossless (maybe)
            if (_jpegQuality == 100 && !jWriteParam.isCompressionLossless())
                continue;
            jWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(toJavaJpegQuality());
        }
    }
}
catch (UnsupportedOperationException e)
{
    // this shouldn't get here, but you should consider what to do if it does.
    // set a default? throw?
}
```

here is getTiffCompressor():

```
private TIFFCompressor getTiffCompressor (TiffCompression compression, TIFFImageWriteParam writeParam, boolean usePredictor)
{
    int predictor = usePredictor 
            ? BaselineTIFFTagSet.PREDICTOR_HORIZONTAL_DIFFERENCING 
            : BaselineTIFFTagSet.PREDICTOR_NONE;

    switch (compression) 
    {
    case GROUP_3_FAX_ENCODING:
        return new TIFFT4Compressor();
    case GROUP_4_FAX_ENCODING:
        return new TIFFT6Compressor();
    case JPEG_COMPRESSION:
        return new TIFFJPEGCompressor(writeParam);
    case MACINTOSH_PACKBITS:
        return new TIFFPackBitsCompressor();
    case DEFLATE:
        return new TIFFDeflateCompressor(writeParam, predictor);
    case LZW:
        return new TIFFLZWCompressor(predictor);
    case MODIFIED_HUFFMAN:
        return new TIFFRLECompressor();
    case NO_COMPRESSION:
    case DEFAULT:
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

TiffCompression is my own enum that models the compressions that I offer for TIFF files.  Finally, here is getCompressionType():

```
private String getCompressionType (TiffCompression compression)
{
    switch (compression)
    {
    case GROUP_3_FAX_ENCODING:
        return "CCITT T.4";
    case GROUP_4_FAX_ENCODING:
        return "CCITT T.6";
    case JPEG_COMPRESSION:
        return "JPEG";
    case MACINTOSH_PACKBITS:
        return "PackBits";
    case DEFLATE:
        return "Deflate";
    case LZW:
        return "LZW";
    case MODIFIED_HUFFMAN:
        return "CCITT RLE";
    case NO_COMPRESSION:
    case DEFAULT:
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, I can't show you everything because my code is built to encode an arbitrary number of images and yours is not, so our code structures differ wildly.  In my case, I set up the encoder for using a sequence writer with a much more open architecture.  I pull in an image, fire an event to optionally change the default compression, create the writer and write param, set metadata/image tags, fire progress events then write the sequence.  Then I have to go in and patch the last written ifd because the tiff encoder writes them broken, so they need to be patched.

Comment: I want to say that the compression aspect is working (somewhere in the neighborhood of 50% file size remaining), but I've never tried doing multipage this way (I typically use JAI. But whenever I compress the individual pages with the above mentioned method and try to reconcile them with JAI, the file size compression is gone). After reading up on it, it appears JAI doesn't support LZW due to patents at the time of its development.